# Is time the collapse of quantum superposition across the universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, superposition, wavefunction-collapse

Just to preface, I admit I'm not a physicist, or even well-read on science-related things (though I do read articles from various aggregate sites and sometimes purchase New Scientist) but I am interested and sometimes a question or piques my interest.

My question is based on the following thought experiment (which is probably based on an incorrect interpretation but I digress):

1. A person is walking down the street
2. They come to a stop at a crossroads
3. Until they do something they are in superposition of all possible things:

   - Go left
   - Go right
   - Go forwards
   - Go backwards
   - Jump up and down
   - Sit down
   - Do nothing
   - etc.
4. It is only when the person moves does their state collapse and they are no longer in superposition
5. Everything is in superposition all the time, it is only from the movement from impetus, be it a person moving or a light particle being emitted in a specific direction does their state collapse
6. The entire universe is in a constant state of superposition for all particles and collapse of said particles regardless of configuration (person, planet, star, liquid water)
7. Time is the constant state of superposition of state and collapse of that state into the next supposition
8. Side thought: Parallel universes formed from simultaneous collapse of other states alongside ours?

Is any of this right or am I just plain wrong?

Comment: I think that the phrase "plain wrong" tends to understate just how wrong this is.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that you are plain wrong, assuming that is, that you are using the words 'state', superposition' and 'collapse' in the sense in which they are usually used in connection with quantum mechanics.

If you are using those words in a different sense, then your question is one of philosophy, not physics, and it is out of scope for this site.

State, superposition and collapse have very specific meanings in quantum theory, and relate to mathematical functions that are used to model the behaviour of matter at an extremely small scale. They are not meaningfully applicable to matter on a large scale.